# Shifting hue/saturation/lightness of an image to meet an exact value in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

Is there a way in Photoshop to adjust the hue/saturation/lightness for an image such that the average value for all pixels would match an RGB value specified?

If not, is there a tool out there to do this without fudging the hue/saturation/lightness by hand?

Comment: Hi CoryG, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Since this is a rootfinding problem, and its unlikely that PS or any other graphics app has a suitable optimization algorithm i would suggest you go to SO or superuser. But no such a algorithm is not hard to script even with JSX but brings us uncomfortably close to linear algebra for GD.SE

Comment: For Gimp there is something you may find interesting: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18831/normalizing-hematoxylin-and-eosin-stained-histology-images (shown for histology slides but works on different sources too).